# Limit of a elementary function

Tags: algebra-precalculus, limits

I am having trouble with the following question:

> find the limit as $x\to-2$ of $f(x) = \frac{\sqrt{4-x^2}}{x+2}$.

I cannot solve it as long as I can't get rid of a denominator that gets zero as $x$ approaches $-2$.
I tried to make a "difference of squares" on the top side and tried to multiply and divide the function by $(x-2)$, but I am still stuck.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Note that $4 - x^2 = (2 - x)(2 + x)$ and remember $\sqrt{ab} = \sqrt{a} \sqrt{b}$ for $a,b \geq 0$.

Comment: @Azlif , I tried this method and i get $\frac{\sqrt[]{2-x}}{\sqrt[]{2+x}}$ 
My denominator still results zero as x approaches to -2

Comment: @Yalita Correct. Now let's "subtitute" the value $x = -2$. We got $2/0$ which is not an indetereminate form. What would be the value of $2/0$?

Comment: @Azlif But we can't divide by zero, right?

Comment: @Yalita What Azlif is trying to say is that the limit, most likely, doesn't exist : because if it did, then it would likely be equal to $\frac 20$, but $\frac 20$ is undefined. You should try to rigorously prove that the limit doesn't exist, by using the representation $\frac{\sqrt{2-x}}{\sqrt{2+x}}$. Assume that this limit exists, and derive a contradiction with limit rules.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon I question your last comment.  I agree that it is appropriate for $\lim_{x \to (-2)^+} \frac{\sqrt{2 - x}}{\sqrt{2 + x}}$, since the denominator is defined for $x > -2.$  However, the question calls for the **two-sided** limit, and the pertinent denominator is undefined for $x < -2.$  In the pre-Calculus world, with L'Hopital's rule (and any derivatives) excluded, the difficulty strikes me as problematic.  I question whether my issue represents an oversight of the problem composer.

Comment: @user2661923 You make a very good point. I should have realized that the two-sided limit was being called for, and in that case your comments resonate! It is certainly my oversight, if not the composer's. I should add that my comments were based on the limit $x \to -2^{+}$ (a region just to the right of $-2$, where the function is well defined) of the function in question (and even this turns out to be not defined/infinite, so ...!) Thanks for the questioning of my comment, I agree I oversaw the directional aspect.

Comment: I am not an expert in complex analysis or real analysys. Is my answer wrong?

Comment: @lonestudent No, I wouldn't say that.  I would say that your answer may be using Math that the OP has not studied yet.  It is unclear if the OP has studied Complex Numbers.  To take an extreme viewpoint, if you had used L'Hopital's rule instead, then the same issue would have arisen, only here the issue would have been more clear cut.  That is, the pre-Calculus world doesn't know from L'Hopital's rule.

Comment: @user2661923 Then lets say, if $x\to (-2)^{+}$ then the limit is $+\infty$. But, $x\to (-2)^{-}$ then the limit is undefined in $\mathbb R$. Because, square root is undefined in $\mathbb R$. This means , the limit doesn't exist. So, we didn't use $i$.

Comment: @lonestudent This is where the issue gets murky.  Suppose that Complex Analysis is outlawed.  Since the denominator of the original question involves $(x + 2)$, rather than $\sqrt{x + 2}$ you have that as $x \to 2^-$ the numerator is undefined and the denominator is approaching $0$ **from below**.  To me, it is unclear what to make of this, in the pre-Calculus - Real Analysis world.